# "No module named video" error in OpenCV-Python (Pycharm IDE)

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

# built-in modules
import sys

# local modules
import video

if __name__ == '__main__':

    hsv_map = np.zeros((180, 256, 3), np.uint8)
    h, s = np.indices(hsv_map.shape[:2])
    hsv_map[:,:,0] = h
    hsv_map[:,:,1] = s
    hsv_map[:,:,2] = 255
    hsv_map = cv.cvtColor(hsv_map, cv.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv.imshow('hsv_map', hsv_map)

    cv.namedWindow('hist', 0)
    hist_scale = 10

    def set_scale(val):
        global hist_scale
        hist_scale = val
    cv.createTrackbar('scale', 'hist', hist_scale, 32, set_scale)

    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except:
        fn = 0
    cam = video.create_capture(fn, 
fallback='synth:bg=../data/baboon.jpg:class=chess:noise=0.05')

    while True:
        flag, frame = cam.read()
        cv.imshow('camera', frame)

        small = cv.pyrDown(frame)

        hsv = cv.cvtColor(small, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dark = hsv[...,2] < 32
        hsv[dark] = 0
        h = cv.calcHist([hsv], [0, 1], None, [180, 256], [0, 180, 0, 256])

        h = np.clip(h*0.005*hist_scale, 0, 1)
        vis = hsv_map*h[:,:,np.newaxis] / 255.0
        cv.imshow('hist', vis)

        ch = cv.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

OpenCV - 3.4.1
This is the color histogram default code that comes with OpenCV-Python.

When I tried this code in Pycharm, it gives me "No module named video" message.

I tried some solutions from SOF and tried searching on the internet but I couldn't really solve or understand the problem properly.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: do you actually have a `video.py` file in the same folder as this script? or a `video` folder with an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: @OferSadan I added the video.py file in my project folder and now it says "ImportError: No module named 'tst_scene_render".

Comment: So your problem is solved and you have a new problem... open another question, and if you want good answers about `ImportError` you should always include what your project folder structure is

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by structure here? can you give an example?

Comment: You have a folder and inside that folder there are files and other folders, we need to see what that looks like and where each file is, `import` statements are very sensitive to that... as you've just learned by fixing the problem in your question

Comment: ok. Thanks. It is like this:
/home/"username"/PycharmProjects/2DHistogram/2DHistogram.py

Comment: yes, but for all the files and folders in your project

Comment: Okay. I will keep this in mind. Thanks.
PS : Idk why this question of mine was downvoted!!!